# how to merge two dataframe with different times and sizes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge these two dataframe together and preserve all the rows and columns. They have different times under the column 'time', so i want them to merge in a way that is time sequential.

df1:

| time | run_id | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | H1 | 500 |
| 24 | H1 | 400 |
| 48 | H1 | 300 |
| 0 | H2 | 900 |
| 24 | H2 | 800 |
| 48 | H2 | 700 |

df2:

| time | run_id | totalizer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.5 | H1 | 100 |
| 10 | H1 | 200 |
| 40 | H1 | 300 |
| 60 | H1 | 400 |
| 0.5 | H2 | 900 |
| 5 | H2 | 1000 |
| 35 | H2 | 1100 |
| 70 | H2 | 1200 |

How do I merge these two tables into:

| time | run_id | weight | totalizer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | H1 | 500 |  |
| 0.5 | H1 |  | 100 |
| 10 | H1 |  | 200 |
| 24 | H1 | 400 |  |
| 40 | H1 |  | 300 |
| 48 | H1 | 300 |  |
| 60 | H1 |  | 400 |
| 0 | H2 | 900 |  |
| 0.5 | H2 |  | 900 |
| 5 | H2 |  | 1000 |
| 24 | H2 | 800 |  |
| 35 | H2 |  | 1100 |
| 48 | H2 | 700 |  |
| 70 | H2 |  | 1200 |

I tried:

```
mergedf = df1.merge(df2, how='outer')
```

but it stacked df1 on top of df2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) :

```
cols = ["run_id", "time"]
​
out = (
        df1.set_index(cols)
              .combine_first(df2.set_index(cols))
              .reset_index().sort_values(by=cols)
           [["time", "run_id", "weight", "totalizer"]]
       )
```

​Output :

```
print(out)

    time run_id  weight  totalizer
0    0.0     H1   500.0        NaN
1    0.5     H1     NaN      100.0
2   10.0     H1     NaN      200.0
3   24.0     H1   400.0        NaN
4   40.0     H1     NaN      300.0
5   48.0     H1   300.0        NaN
6   60.0     H1     NaN      400.0
7    0.0     H2   900.0        NaN
8    0.5     H2     NaN      900.0
9    5.0     H2     NaN     1000.0
10  24.0     H2   800.0        NaN
11  35.0     H2     NaN     1100.0
12  48.0     H2   700.0        NaN
13  70.0     H2     NaN     1200.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add line after what you have already done:

```py
mergedf = df1.merge(df2, how='outer') # your current code
mergedf.sort_values(['run_id', 'time']) # add this
```

Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17141755/2650341

Answer (score 1):

You can use panda's `merge_ordered`

```
df_merged=pd.merge_ordered(df1,df2, on=['run_id','time'])
```