# df.groupby() - how to aggregate data where order of grouped data is important?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, pandas-groupby

**How can I aggregate data when the order of grouped data is important?** (bonus points if this can be done in an elegant vectorized way). If that was clear as mud, let me explain with an example.

---

Let's say I have data in `df`:

```
id    month              value
------------------------------
001   2019-01-01 (Jan)     111
001   2019-02-01 (Feb)     222
001   2019-03-01 (Mar)     333

002   2019-01-01 (Jan)       0
002   2019-02-01 (Feb)       0
002   2019-03-01 (Mar)      25

...   ...                  ...

999   2019-01-01 (Jan)     800
999   2019-02-01 (Feb)     600
999   2019-03-01 (Mar)     400
```

I can use `groupby` to aggregate the data over each `id`:

```
df.groupby('id')['value'].agg([numpy.sum, numpy.mean])
```

Whether I use `numpy.sum`, `numpy.mean`, `numpy.max`, etc. as the aggregating function, the order of the isolated array that is grouped doesn't matter (e.g., `[111, 222, 333]` for `id=001`) - the result will always be the same.

---

However, there are some aggregations where the order does matter - for example, I may want to calculate:

- a weighted average (e.g., if more recent values have more weight)
- a start-to-finish change (e.g., `Mar` - `Jan`)
- etc.

Currently, I loop through each `id` and then:

1. filter the data through `df[df['id']==id]`
2. get a list of month-value tuples, e.g. `[(Jan,111), (Feb,222), (Mar,333)]`
3. sort list based on the first element of each tuple, i.e., `'month'`
4. perform aggregation

For example, if I just wanted to find the **difference between the first and last elements of that sorted array**, then I'd end up with this:

```
id    finish_minus_start
------------------------
001                  222
002                   25
...                  ...
999                 -400
```

---

**How can I aggregate data when the order of grouped data is important?**

Can I do this more efficiently by making use of vectorization instead of looping through each `id`?

Comment: Maybe this solution helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995771/pandas-sorting-by-group-aggregate It computes a previous order to rearrange the grouping

Comment: @BCJuan - thanks - this looks potentially useful. That solution will order `df` such that for each `id`, the rows will be sorted by `'month'`. Good start. But can you confirm that when aggregating on this sorted `df`, that the order of those rows are reflected in the values that are passed into the aggregating function (e.g., `numpy.mean(x)`)? i.e., that the isolated values aren't jiggled about under-the-hood for some reason that I can't comprehend.

Comment: what about something like `df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('month'))`?

Comment: I guess vectorized functions are only available for the most common operations, for rest of them, we have to use: `df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: User_Defined_function(x))`

Comment: @hacker315 - can you be a little more explicit, since I'm struggling to see the solution! Say I wanted my user-defined function to be `difference_between_first_and_last_elements()`, how would I define that function to return a single value for each `id`? i.e., `sorted_list[-1] - sorted_list[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you were looking for.
You can use aggregates and set your own function. I took an example from two links
[Summarizing and Grouping data](https://www.shanelynn.ie/summarising-aggregation-and-grouping-data-in-python-pandas/) and [First and Last Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001237/how-to-apply-first-and-last-functions-to-columns-while-using-group-by-in-pan) and played around a little.

```
df= df.set_index('date')
aggregations = {
    'value': lambda x: x.loc[x.index.max()] - x.loc[x.index.min()]
}
print(df.groupby('id').agg(aggregations))
```

Comment: At the moment, I think this just finds the difference between the first and last elements in the `value` column (good) but I'm not guaranteed that those first and last elements are defined by what's in the corresponding `month` column (bad) - it could just be randomly ordered for all I know. Can you amend your answer so that the result would yield the dataframe I displayed at the bottom of my original post?

Comment: Edited. If i understand correctly, this should be it. You will need to assign a date column for this then index it.

Comment: Many thanks - this works :) although I'm a little nervy using it since I don't properly understand what's going on (although that's down to my limited knowledge of lambda functions). How does the lambda function know what to do with the `value` column - I don't see it referenced anywhere within the lambda function?

Comment: Just see lambda as a single line function. You can try create a separate function to help you understand... 
func_a(df): 
return x.loc[x.index.max()] and etc.....
From my understanding of how it works..
Similarly, the dataframe df is thrown into func_a(df). 
The aggregations Dict has a key named: "value" and value as a function result from column "value", it is then returned to aggregate.