# Pandas: Summarize table based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My Pandas Dataframe is in this format:

```
A    5
A    7
A    4
B    2
B    7
C    8
```

How could I summarize to this:

```
A    16
B    9
C    8
```

Comment: Looks very close or duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941366/pandas-sort-by-group-aggregate-and-column.

Comment: Did you read the doc? [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
  col1  col2
0   A   5
1   A   7
2   A   4
3   B   2
4   B   7
5   C   8

df.groupby('col1')['col2'].sum()
col1
A    16
B     9
C     8
```

If you want to keep the columns as they are, as you mentioned in your comment, you can convert the `groupby` object to a new dataframe, if this is what you meant. So, you can do this instead:

```
new = pd.DataFrame({'col2' : df.groupby('col1')['col2'].sum()}).reset_index()
new
  col1  col2
0   A   16
1   B   9
2   C   8
```

Comment: Thanks for the rapid answer. One small problem: the columns are no longer called "col1" and "col2". Is it possible to add another line of code so that the columns retain their names?

Comment: @NedHulton I added a new solution to my answer based on your comment. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) for that with `sum` as aggregation function:

```
In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
   0  1
0  A  5
1  A  7
2  A  4
3  B  2
4  B  7
5  C  8

In [10]: df.pivot_table(index=0, aggfunc=sum).reset_index()
Out[10]: 
   0   1
0  A  16
1  B   9
2  C   8
```