# Is there a more efficient way to call functions with different arguments multiple times?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, pandas, for-loop

At the moment I've got the following function that iterates through a Pandas DataFrame (`df`) column and creates a count:

```
def my_function(my_argument):
    count = 0
    for i, row in df.iterrows(): 
        if row['MyColumn'] == my_argument:
            count += row['MyScore']
    return count
```

I have many arguments to assign to/call the function - For now, I am doing the following:

```
c = my_function('My_String1')
p = my_function('My_String13')
l = my_function('My_String342')
d = my_function('My_String14')
a = my_function('My_String49')
t = my_function('My_String553')
q = my_function('My_String42')
e = my_function('My_String99')
x = my_function('My_String123')
... ETC...
```

Doing so, works just fine, however I was wondering whether there is a more practical/efficient way that would achieve the same outcome.

I was thinking of adding the variable names e.g. `c`, `p`, `l`, `d` etc. to a list and forming some sort of loop - ***If*** that would even work...

Thereby, maybe something a little like:

```
for variable_name in list_of_variables:
    # ??? ... But I'm unaware of what would go here.
```

Or alternatively, is there a method using Pandas?

Comment: Have you looked at `groupby`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941366/pandas-sort-by-group-aggregate-and-column

Comment: This is sometimes arcane to set up, but look into the `DataFrame` `apply` and `applymap` functions. (in straight Python, you would just use `map(function, [arg-set-1, arg-set-1, arg-set-3])` or a list comprehension `[function(x) for x in (arg-set-1, arg-set-2, arg-set-3)`, but numpy/pandas have their own versions as well, which if they are using numpy/pandas math anyways may be faster (if they aren't, a regular map is probably fine).

Comment: If you use pandas and if you are looping, most of the time you are doing it the wrong way. Pandas saves you looping.

Comment: @doctorlove Mind posting an example? - I've had a look and honestly struggle to understand how I would achieve my outcome using it. Would greatly appreciate an answer :-)

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi Thanks. Although, I don't particularly understand how I could use it to provide the same outcome.

Comment: Looks like lots of ppl gave actual answers - hopefully there are enough to help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandas has a built in method for this, value_counts, which works similar to groupby, but skips uneeded stuff if you only want counts:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['a','b','c','d','a','a']})
df.x.value_counts()


a    3
b    1
d    1
c    1
Name: x, dtype: int64

### using groupby:

df.groupby('x').size()

x
a    3
b    1
c    1
d    1
dtype: int64
```

From there, you could filter out those values you did not want to count (or do it previous to the value_counts() call).

Comment: Thanks for the example! However, How can I relate this to my answer as demonstrated in my function? Since this only seems to create a count for the presence of identical strings. Whereas, I'd like to create a count for different strings from a different column. More specifically, as my function shows: For `row['MyColumn']` being equal to the argument, a count is creating corresponding to the integers stored in `row['MyScore']`

Comment: something like: `df.groupby('x').agg(lambda x: np.sum(x.score))`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :) Lastly, How can I add a new column using the results from the above line, because at the moment it seems to replace all the values in the data frame?

Comment: something like: `df.merge(df.groupby('x').agg(lambda x: np.sum(x.score)), left_on = 'x', right_index = True)`

Comment: Thanks, Although that doesn't seem to work, it has repeating integers and columns in a pretty random order :/

Comment: I figured needed a merge between your original dataset and the aggregation, but that looks like it is not the case. You should probably ask a new question, with example data and output after the aggregation.

Comment: I took the long route round, but found that resetting the index would solve the structuring issue and allow extraction of specific columns :)

Answer (score 2):

```
map(lambda x: my_function(x), list_of_variables)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you try `groupby` supported by DataFrame

But if you'd prefer to call your custom function, I would suggest adding the function parameters to an array like `stringList = ["My_String1", "My_String13", ..]` and

```
stringList = ["My_String1", "My_String13", ".."]
results = map(my_function, stringList)
```

The `map` iteratively calls the `my_function` function with each item from the list `stringList`

The return values would be stored in the `results` list.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Works great. I'd really appreciate it if you could possible edit your answer to include the approach in relation to my answer using `groupby` - I've had a look and honestly struggle to understand how I would achieve my outcome using it.

Answer (score 0):

You could store your results in a `dict` instead of in local variables. Then you could use a loop quite easily:

```
results = {}
for var, n in (('c', 1),
               ('p', 13),
               ('l', 342),
              ):
    results[var] = my_function('My_String%d' % n)
```