# How can I sort one column without changing other columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

Example:
Current df looks like:

```
    df=
    A B
    1 5
    2 6
    3 8
    4 1
```

I want the resulting df to be like this (B is sorted and A remains untouched):

```
    df=
    A B
    1 8
    2 6
    3 5
    4 1
```

Comment: check out this stack page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941366/pandas-sort-by-group-aggregate-and-column/14946246#14946246

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to break an internal Pandas security mechanism - `aligning by index`, which takes care of the `data consistency`. So assigning 1D Numpy array or a vanilla Python list would do the trick, because both of them don't have an index, so Pandas can't do alignment:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].sort_values(ascending=False).values
```

or

```
df['B'] = df['B'].sort_values(ascending=False).tolist()
```

both yield:

```
In [77]: df
Out[77]:
   A  B
0  1  8
1  2  6
2  3  5
3  4  1
```

Comment: Or use NumPy: `np.sort(df['B'].values)[::-1]`. +1 anyway.

Comment: @jpp, yeah, this will work well as well :-D Thank you!

Comment: Given the example though... it almost looks like `A` should be the index and then sort by `B` as normal... otherwise - it's remarkably weird to keep `A` as a column that isn't sorted with `B`... Getting a slight feel it's an XY question, but who knows... this does directly and correctly answer the Q though, even though it makes me think it's "ugh" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as well :

```
df['B'] = sorted(df['B'].tolist())[::-1]
```